# ListView with alphabet as in Telegram

Tags: android, listview

How to implements ListView with alphabet as in Telegram? Show to picture.
For example, while we look at the countries that begin with the letter "E", the letter "E" is not scrolling as long as there are countries that begin with the letter "F". Then the letter "E" is changed to the letter "F".

[image]

Comment: Almost what you need http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/12/android-listview-sectionindexer-fastscroll.html

Comment: @BojanKseneman Thank you, I have used it. But how to organize a similar job with scrolling alphabet?

Comment: Yes, that's what is missing and that's why I said almost. I am not familiar with telegram, does the letter in front scroll with the list or it just shows in the front of the first position where the alphabet changes?

Comment: @BojanKseneman The letter does not scroll together with a list as long as the words that are in the list beginning with that letter.

Answer (score 0):

Do this. your `ListItemlayout` will be a `ViewGroup` of `RelativeLayout` and will have  `TextView` aligned to the left, bold, etc, to your requirement-(that will be the alphabet), to the right of this `TextView` a `LinearLayout` with `TextView` and `TextView` and let one `TextView` cheat the other in terms of space with the aid of `Gravity`. Let all those widgets be `GONE` in terms of `visibility`. in your **`GetView`** method check your `String`/`char` at `index` 0 to see if its the previous `String`/`char` or it matches the previous item's `index` 0, if it does no more code logic, if it doesn't then convert that `char` to `String` set your visibility on the alphabet `TextView` to `VISIBLE`, continue this routine.

Since you said the alphabet do not scroll with the items the if the `char`s match no more code let it fly, if it doesn't more code. you will get the same effect as that.